# How to store each JSON data with restsharper in c#?

Tags: c#, restsharp

I need to get the values from the JSON response, I've tried to do the following but the messagebox shows empty in the `Project` class.

I've tried to Google my problem (also restsharp tutorials) but until now I wasn't able to fix the problem that I'm having. I've gotten clues here and there online and this is how far I've gotten over the last few days.

The result I am expecting is that each value from the API goes into the variable, which I can then grab per value. I don't want the plain JSON content.

**Api Class**

```
private async void Submit_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var client = new RestClient("http://apage.com/");
    var request = new RestRequest("api/project");
    request.Method = Method.GET;

    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");

    client.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization",
        string.Format("Bearer {0}", "token goes here"));

    var response = client.Execute(request);

    var deserialize = new JsonDeserializer();
    Project output = deserialize.Deserialize<Project>(response);

    Project project = new Project();
    project.check();
}
```

**Project Class**

```
class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Deadline { get; set; }
    public int User_id { get; set; }
    public string Created_at { get; set; }
    public string Updated_at { get; set; }

    public void check()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Title);
    }
}
```

**JSON Code**

```
{
    "projects": [
        {
            "id": 29,
            "title": "a_project",
            "slug": "a_project",
            "description": "f",
            "deadline": "2020-04-08 00:00:00",
            "user_id": 19,
            "created_at": "2020-02-11 16:59:45",
            "updated_at": "2020-02-11 16:59:45"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Github link:** https://github.com/s1129092/n212/blob/master/WpfApp1/MainWindow.xaml.cs

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing `output.check()` instead of `project.check()`?

Comment: `Project project = new Project();` is a new instance that is null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you're deserializing an object with one property containing an array of `Project` objects into a `Project` class object. Your JSON example shows the root object's property `projects` containing an array of objects, so you'll want to match that in your class design for your deserialization to implicitly work:

```
class ProjectList
{
    public Project[] Projects { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize your response to the new `ProjectList` class:

```
ProjectList output = deserialize.Deserialize<ProjectList>(response);
```

Then you can iterate through the `output.Projects` array to find your project objects.

Your `Submit_Button_Click` method could now work like this:

```
private async void Submit_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var client = new RestClient("http://apage.com/");
    var request = new RestRequest("api/project");
    request.Method = Method.GET;

    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");

    client.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization",
        string.Format("Bearer {0}", "token goes here"));

    var response = client.Execute(request);

    var deserialize = new JsonDeserializer();

    ProjectList output = deserialize.Deserialize<ProjectList>(response);

    Project firstProjectInResponse = output.Projects[0];
    firstProjectInResponse.check();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. So if I understand correctly, I have to first define the `ProjectList` since this is the structure of my JSON. And then make an array instance of my Project class to be able to grab it all 1 by 1? I'm quite new to this, how would I be able to grab the first project for example? Thank you again for your response. (re-posted for updates)

Comment: That's correct, you can define the `ProjectList` class as I have in the answer above, then you shouldn't need to do any extra work to deserialize or map the fields. No need to create an array of Project objects, as that will already exist in the `output.Projects` property in the above example. You can then iterate through the projects to find the data you want, for example if you only have one project in the array, or just want to access the first project, you can access it like so:
`Project p1 = output.Projects[0];`

Comment: Extended the example to include changes to your `Submit_Button_Click` method.

Comment: Hi, thank you again for your time. I understand what you mean now. I've tried this but whenever I try to fill this in a Textbox `tb.Text = firstProjectInResponse.ToString();` it gives me an error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` `WpfApp1.ProjectList.Projects.get returned null.` Do you know why this happens? Wasn't able to fix this sadly.

Comment: @n212: I don't know what the `Projects.get` code is supposed to do, do you have the larger code base available on GitHub or anywhere for a better context? Did the example code above with `firstProjectInResponse.check();` work for you?

Comment: Hi, yes I made a GitHub for my project now. I've edited the post with the link added. Again, thank you.

Comment: I don't think the `.ToString()` method you're calling on the `Project` class object (`firstProjectInResponse`) is going to get the data you're looking for. You have to refer to each property individually like so:

`tb.Text = firstProjectInResponse.Description;`

That will set the text box text value to the `Description` property value of the project object. You'll need to refer to each property individually to get their values.

Comment: That has seemed to fix one issue I was unaware of, thank you. I get this https://prnt.sc/r2w6g4 error saying that the `output.Projects[0]` is not an object reference but did reference as an object?

Comment: The code likely did not parse any project objects from the JSON payload, meaning the resulting object `ProjectList.Projects` is empty or `null`. Can you confirm the response you're getting back from the `RestClient` is good and matches the example you provided in the original question?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a class like this:

```
public class ProjectsModel
{
    public List<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

You can use the following code to get the response data:

```
var response = client.Execute<ProjectsModel>(request).Data;
var projects = response.Projects;
```

Then for example:

```
foreach(Project p in projects)
{
    MessageBox.Show(p.Title);
}
```